# Pushing an object on array of objects returns array size

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I am building an app with the react-boilerplate where people can make and edit events. This boilerplate uses immutable.js so I want to learn it.

When I save an event to the database, the database returns the event as an object.

```
console.log(action.payload.event)
```

would print

```
{
  color:"#000000",
  name:"my Event",
  _id:"59ea882a58a83d20d400cd21",
}
```

This object I then want to push to the array of other events. The events get populated when a user logs in.

My reducer looks like this

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { ADD_EVENT_REQUEST_SUCCESS } from './constants';

const initialState = fromJS({
  events: null
});

function eventsOverviewReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case ADD_EVENT_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
      return state
        .update('events', list => list.push( action.payload.event ));

    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      const user = action.payload.user;
      return state
        .set('events', user.events)

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

However this update statement now sets the events in the store to the size of the array. How do I push my object to the state?

Comment: Well the `.push()` method returns the new array length because that is what it is supposed to do. I don't use Redux, but I'm guessing maybe `list => { list.push( action.payload.event ); return list }` is closer to what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your `events` is not an [Immutable.List](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/List). When you set `events` you should create it as a list instead of a regular array:

```
case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
  return state
    .set('events', List(user.events))
```

Then `events.push` will return the new list correctly.